# payU money complete profile in progress opencart integration proccess

Tags: opencart, payumoney

i have a doubt on payumoney profile complete, i tired to complete my payU integration profile details, should i give my original bank account details or any sample data available for profile complete?

Comment: I guess if you use it for testing purposes you could just use some sample data. But if it's really for a business I would definitely use valid credentials.

Comment: thank you for your replay, i have a doubt on merchant profile complete, should i give my original bank account details?

Comment: If you don't trust their services, why would you consider using them? And if you insist on using them then I think your bank details are crucial for accepting payments.